# How to undef calloc() function from stdlib to use our own function

Tags: c, malloc, calloc, crt, multiple-definition-error

I have a header file **calloc.h**, where I defined calloc() function using stdlib's malloc() function. But I am getting `multiple definition of 'calloc'` error.

**calloc.h**:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void *calloc(size_t num, size_t size)
{
    /* num * size unsigned integer wrapping check */
    if ((num >= MUL_NO_OVERFLOW || size >= MUL_NO_OVERFLOW) && num > 0 && SIZE_MAX / num < size)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    size_t total_size = num * size;
    void *ptr = malloc(total_size);

    if (ptr)
    {
        memset(ptr, 0, total_size);
    }

    return ptr;
}
```

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

I tried this:

```
#define calloc _calloc_

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#undef calloc
```

But I am getting the following error:

`cstdlib:144:11: error: 'calloc' has not been declared in '::'`

`stdlib.h:59:12: error: 'calloc' has not been declared in 'std'`

Comment: You get multiple definition of 'calloc' because you define it in the header file.

Comment: *I have a header file calloc.h, where I defined calloc() function using stdlib's malloc() function.*  First, why?  Second, if you're running on Linux or any other POSIX system you're invoking [undefined behavior](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02_02): "Each identifier with external linkage described in the header section is reserved for use as an identifier with external linkage if the header is included."

Comment: Your biggest problem is actually that you are compiling C with a C++ compiler. If you don't even know what compiler you are using, there's no hope of ever producing a reliable and working program.

Answer (score 0):

The link time error you get seems to indicate the module in the C library that defines `calloc()` is linked into your program, not because you redefoine `calloc`, but because you use at least another symbol defined in the same module.  It is possible that both `calloc` and `malloc` are defined in the same module in your C library, which means you cannot redefine `calloc()` with a call to `malloc()`.

Also note that you seem to be compiling your C source file as C++.

On your system, you may have to redefine both `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`, `free()` and possibly other library functions such as `strdup()`, `aligned_alloc()`, so none of the original allocation modules get pulled into your executable.  This is a non trivial task.

If you want to divert the calls to `calloc()` in a program, you can add a command line definition such as `-Dcalloc=my_calloc` so all source files end up calling your function instead of the standard library function.